# iBatis Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'

Tags: java, xml, xpath, ibatis

i'm new to ibatis. i like to split the SQLMapConfig file and SQL map resources into 2 file. but when i run the project its seems to show an error.
so below are my 2 file SQL Map.

1. **SQLMapConfig.xml**  :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig PUBLIC "-//iBATIS.com//DTD SQL Map Config 
     2.0//EN" "http://www.ibatis.com/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">
   <sqlMapConfig>
      <settings
       cacheModelsEnabled="true"
       enhancementEnabled="true"
       lazyLoadingEnabled="true"
       maxRequests="32"
       maxSessions="10"
       maxTransactions="5"
       useStatementNamespaces="false"
      />

     <transactionManager type="JDBC" >
       <dataSource type="DBCP">
         <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms_converter"/>
         <property name="JDBC.Username" value="root"/>
         <property name="JDBC.Password" value=""/>
       </dataSource>
     </transactionManager>
     <sqlMap resource="configuration/db/tbluser.xml" />
   </sqlMapConfig>
   ```

and here is the SQL Map resources **tbluser.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//iBATIS.com//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://www.ibatis.com/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">
<sqlMap namespace="MUser">
    <select id="getUserById" parameterClass = "com.me.bean.MUser" resultClass="com.me.bean.MUser">
        SELECT user_id AS sUserId FROM users where user.id = #sUserId#
    </select>
</sqlMap>
```

but after i run the project i've got this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource configuration/db/tbluser.xml
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:49)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientBuilder.java:63)
    at com.me.dao.DBDao.main(DBDao.java:77)
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource configuration/db/tbluser.xml
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:53)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:46)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource configuration/db/tbluser.xml
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.processNodelet(NodeletParser.java:123)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:84)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:102)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:72)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:51)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource configuration/db/tbluser.xml
    at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:110)
    at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:95)
    at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.getResourceAsReader(Resources.java:161)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser$10.process(SqlMapConfigParser.java:262)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.processNodelet(NodeletParser.java:121)
    ... 7 more
```

can anyone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find resource configuration/db/tbluser.xml, so try add prefix classpath:

```
<mapper resource="classpath:configuration/db/tbluster.xml">
```

Comment: thanks, but i've resolve this by moving my tbluser.xml inside the src package.

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
<typeAlias alias="classMUser" type="com.me.bean.MUser" />

<resultMap id="userMap" class="classMUser">
    <result property="sUserId" column="sUserId" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getUserById" parameterClass = "com.me.bean.MUser" resultMap="userMap">
    SELECT user_id AS sUserId FROM users where user.id = #sUserId#
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was:

```
<select id="someId" parameterClass="hashmap"
    resultClass="someResultClass" resultMap="someResultMap">
```

I have written "**hashmap**" in **resultMap** instead of "**someResultMap**".

Correcting this solved the compilation issue.